# django post_signal triggered on form.save(commit=False)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a base **User** model and two other models **Candidate** and **Company**

```
User:
  email
  password
  is_company => default=False
```

Form class:

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Enter email', widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email Address', 'spellcheck':'False', 'autofocus':'True'}))
    password = forms.CharField(label='Enter password', min_length=8, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password'}))

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email'].lower()
        r = User.objects.filter(email=email)
        if r.count():
            raise  ValidationError("Email already exists")
        return email

    def clean_password(self):
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        return password

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            self.cleaned_data['email'],
            self.cleaned_data['password']
        )
        return user
```

My UserManager:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
        """
        try:
            validate_email(email)
            valid_email = True
        except ValidationError:
            valid_email = False
        if not valid_email:
            raise ValueError('Valid Email is required')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        subject = 'Activate Your Account'
        message = render_to_string('registration/account_activation_email.html', {
            'domain': 'example.in',
            'user': user,
            'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
            'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
        })
        user.email_user(subject, 'example <admin@example.in>', html_message=message)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

In my user creation view:

```
class SignUpView(View):
    is_company = False
    def get(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return redirect(reverse_lazy('dashboard'))
        form = CustomUserCreationForm()
        return render(request, 'registration/signup.html', {'form': form, 'is_company':self.is_company})

    def post(self,request):
        form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user.is_company = self.is_company
            user.save()
            return render(request, 'registration/account_activation_sent.html')
        return render(request, 'registration/signup.html', {'form': form, 'is_company':self.is_company})
```

I have created a post_save signal for the above model.

```
  @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
  def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
      if created:
          if instance.is_company:
              Company.objects.create(user=instance)
              instance.company.save()
        else:
            Candidate.objects.create(user=instance, 
                                   first_name=instance.is_company )
            instance.candidate.save()
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^accounts/signup/company/',vw.SignUpView.as_view(is_company = True), name='signup_company')
```

The problem is the `form.save(commit=False)` is triggering the post_save signal. I end up having `instance.is_company` as `False`, thus creating a CandidateProfile for a Company.

But the the database user table is populated with is_company as True for the company.

Please help!

Comment: Can you show form class?

Comment: @neverwalkaloner Yeah. Added everything I have. Please check.

Comment: You've overwritten the `save` method so that it ignores the value of the `commit` argument and always just does a create.

Comment: Is post_save signal triggered even when commit=False?

Comment: As I said, your code *ignores* the commit argument. The signal is triggered by your call to `User.objects.create_user()`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have updated the question with UserManager. Help me.

Answer (score 1):

You should try disconnecting the post_save signal before working on your instance and connecting it later.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    # disconnect post_save
    post_save.disconnect(update_user_profile, sender=sender)

    # do something with your instance

    # connect post_save
    post_save.connect(update_user_profile, sender=sender)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your form you have overridden `save` and are always calling `create_user` which will call `user.save(using=self._db)` i.e not passing the value of `commit`

What you can do is override `_create_user` in your User model to pass the value of commit to it

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    ...
    def _create_user(self, username, email, password, commit=True, **extra_fields):            
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('The given username must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        username = self.model.normalize_username(username)
        user = self.model(username=username, email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        if commit:
            user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

And then in your form you can pass the value of commit to it

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(forms.Form):
    def save(self, commit=True):
        return User.objects.create_user(
            self.cleaned_data['email'],
            self.cleaned_data['password'],
            commit=False
        )
```

**Edit:** Looking into this code again, I feel it is bad.
You're better off fixing your logic in the form to do multiple saves

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(forms.Form):
    def save(self, commit=True):
        is_create = self.instance.pk is None
        user = super().save(commit=commit)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password'])
        user.save()
        if not is_create:
            return user

        if user.is_company:
            Company.objects.create(user=user)
            user.company.save()  # not really needed
        else:
            Candidate.objects.create(user=user, first_name=user.is_company)
            user.candidate.save()  # not really needed
        return user
```

P.S: I personally dislike django signal as they can cause confusion as to what is happening. It might be better to do this in your view or in the form save instead. You should have only one way of creating new users so it shouldn't be a big problem.

Comment: `user.save(using=self._db, commit=commit)` unknown arguement commit.

Answer (score 0):

Change your argument to default False and check if this is true before saving... with your way doenst matter if you call it with commit false or true, they will always save in data base... so because of that they are triggers your post_save

```
def save(self, commit=False):
    if commit:
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            self.cleaned_data['email'],
            self.cleaned_data['password']
        )
```